# NoMethodError using order intermittently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubinius

I am getting the following error in a production rails application intermittently

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `values' on priority:Symbol.):
  app/controllers/things_controller.rb:33:in `index'
```

The offending line looks like this:

```
@things = Thing.where(:some_column => 'some_value').order(:priority).reverse
```

Thing is an activerecord model.

The weird thing is, when I restart the application the error disappears. It is only under some strange set of circumstances that this happens (which I can't reproduce in preprod/dev environments).

Has anyone come across something like this before? Can anyone suggest how I would go about diagnosing this bug? The line in question doesn't seem to be the problem (the logs in production also don't show the full stacktrace)

Comment: I actually think this may be a bug in rails 4.1.6. Rolled back to 4.1.5 and the issue (and some others) have disappeared. Will leave question open for now in case anyone else has similar problems.

Comment: Actually that didn't fix this issue. Still happening intermittently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a length hair pulling session, I discovered that this is due to a bug in rubinius (2.2.10, and 2.2.9). The ActiveRecord query methods `where` and `order` both call enumerable#grep internally. After the application has been running for some time, or some unknown conditions are met, this function stops behaving correctly when the array contains symbols.

When a block is given as an argument to the grep function, this block will always be applied to the symbol elements of the array, regardless of the pattern given.

Bug report is [here](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/issues/3122)